# PySpark Sql with column name containing dash/hyphen in it

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've PySpark dataframe df

```
data = {'Passenger-Id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},'Age': {0: 22, 1: 38, 2: 26, 3: 35, 4: 35}}
df_pd = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.keys())
df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)
```

```
+------------+---+
|Passenger-Id|Age|
+------------+---+
|           1| 22|
|           2| 38|
|           3| 26|
|           4| 35|
|           5| 35|
+------------+---+
```

This works

```
   df.filter(df.Age == 22).show()
```

But below doesn't work, due to - in the column name

```
    df.filter(df.Passenger-Id == 2).show()
```

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Passenger'

I'm facing same issue in spark sql too,

```
        spark.sql("SELECT  Passenger-Id FROM AutoMobile").show()

        spark.sql("SELECT  automobile.Passenger-Id FROM AutoMobile").show()
```

Getting below error

AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Passenger`' given input columns: [automobile.Age, automobile.Passenger-Id]

Tried giving the column name with in single quote, as advised in some sources, now it just prints column mentioned in query

```
  spark.sql("SELECT  'Passenger-Id' FROM AutoMobile").show()
```

```
+------------+
|Passenger-Id|
+------------+
|Passenger-Id|
|Passenger-Id|
|Passenger-Id|
|Passenger-Id|
|Passenger-Id|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you  have hiphen in column name, I suggest you to use `col()` function from `sql.functions`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.filter(F.col('Passenger-Id')== 2).show()
```

Here is the result

```
+------------+---+
|Passenger-Id|Age|
+------------+---+
|           2| 38|
+------------+---+
```

Noe for sql syntax, you need to use special character " ` " not single quote, like below

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("AutoMobile")
spark.sql("SELECT  * FROM AutoMobile where `Passenger-Id`=2").show()
```

Comment: The below worked for me , double quotes inside a single quote.

import pyspark.sql.functions as F 

df.filter(F.col('"Passenger-Id"')== 2).show()

Answer (score -1):

The below worked for me, double quotes inside a single quote.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 

df.filter(F.col('"Passenger-Id"')== 2).show()
```